# I've to stop button animation after tap and navigates to another screen in android

Tags: android, animation

I've written the code for a button to animate it and navigate to the other screen. It is done successfully. But the navigation is done before completion of the animation of the button for that I need to stop or pause the animation for sometime and have to navigate to the other screen after the completion of animation.

main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"     

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/myborder"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:radius="12.0dip"
   android:height="30dp"        
    android:textColor="#009900"
    android:text="@string/mystring"
    android:topLeftRadius="12.0dip"
    android:topRightRadius="12.0dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="set1"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

myborder.xml:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item>
             <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:shape="rectangle"> 
            <solid android:color="#ffcccc"/>
               <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
                 android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
           android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
          <stroke
              android:color="@android:color/white"
             android:width="1dp" 
                 />
               <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            </shape>
              </item>
            </selector>
```

activity.java:

```
        package com.example.button;
       import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.Intent;
          import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.Menu;
         import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
         import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
         import android.view.animation.Animation;
        import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
          import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageButton;
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           final Animation myscale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.drawable.scale);
         Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         v.startAnimation(myscale);//animation starts  
       Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                                                  Uri.parse("http://www.oneness.com"));//navigating to the website 
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                            }       });
```

BY this code my output is acting like this:
if user tap on that button, it is navigating to the URL mentioned in the code. I am unable to see the animation clearly. I want to pause or stop animation for a while and then it automatically navigate to mentioned URL.

Issue: User unable to see the animation as it is navigating to the mentioned link without showing any animation.

Requirement: Need to show the complete animation to the user before navigating to another screen or to the link.

Comment: Insufficient information. Better to add your code and explain your problem accordingly.

Comment: what is the problem u have ? explain it not proper question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code.....

```
 package com.example.button;
           import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
            import android.content.Context;
           import android.content.Intent;
              import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.Bundle;
             import android.view.Menu;
             import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.view.View;
             import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
             import android.view.animation.Animation;
            import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
              import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ImageButton;
            public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
            @Override
              protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               final Animation myscale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.drawable.scale);
             Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
             b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             v.startAnimation(myscale);//animation starts 

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                                                  Uri.parse("http://www.oneness.com"));//navigating to the website 
                            startActivity(browserIntent);

                }
            }, 2000);

     }       });
```

Comment: This will hold on for 2 seconds and then move further. If you to increase the time just change that 2000 to desired like if you want 3 second then 3000...Happy Coding

Comment: How to deactivate another button's animation(User should not able to navigate to another screen using any other button until the completion of  pressed button animation and navigation) when one button in animation? Can you Please help for this also @Akash